# how to execute parallel testing in cucumber

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cucumber

I need to execute two test cases using parallel testing in Cucumber.

What I have now is two test cases. One will open google.com and the other will open youtube.com. I've added certain dependencies in pom.xml and made some configs.

Also I've added the runner classes.

This is the google test case, runner class and feature file contents:

```
package com.cucumber.learning;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

public class GoogleTest {

public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

@Given("go to google")
public static void main() {

    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=iHJrV_DiJ8SL8QfEipjgBg");

}

}
```

google runner class

```
package com.cucumber.learning;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources/com/cucumber/learning"
    //,glue={"stepDefinition"}
    )

public class GoogleRunnerIT {

}
```

google feature file: [feature file name: 1.google.feature]

```
@Google
Feature: Google test

 Scenario: navigate to google
 Given go to google
```

I've made similar to above code for youtube.com test case also.

the pom.xml code is as shown below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.bdd</groupId>
<artifactId>CucumberModule</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>acceptance-test</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*RunnerIT.class</include>
                        </includes>
                        <parallel>all</parallel>
                        <threadCountSuites>2</threadCountSuites>
                        <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

When I execute the above project in Eclipse using "Run as 'Maven Test'", I receive the BUILD SUCCESS message but no browser is opening or the test case is executing.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Console Error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.bdd:CucumberModule:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 39, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CucumberModule 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ CucumberModule ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/test/workspace/customparalleltesting/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ CucumberModule ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ CucumberModule ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ CucumberModule ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ CucumberModule ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/test/workspace/customparalleltesting/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] Using configured provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider
[INFO] parallel='none', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=0, useUnlimitedThreads=false, threadCountSuites=0, threadCountClasses=0, threadCountMethods=0, parallelOptimized=true

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
 -------------------------------------------------------
 Running com.cucumber.learning.YoutubeTest
 Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.cucumber.learning.YoutubeTest
initializationError(com.cucumber.learning.YoutubeTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< ERROR!
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: 

Classes annotated with @RunWith(Cucumber.class) must not define any
Step Definition or Hook methods. Their sole purpose is to serve as
```

an entry point for JUnit. Step Definitions and Hooks should be defined
in their own classes. This allows them to be reused across features.
Offending class: class com.cucumber.learning.YoutubeTest

```
   at     cucumber.runtime.junit.Assertions.assertNoCucumberAnnotatedMethods(Assertions.java:13)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:40)
at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:80)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:75)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.createRequestAndRun(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:97)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.executeEager(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:78)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:54)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:144)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)

Running com.cucumber.learning.GoogleTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.cucumber.learning.GoogleTest
initializationError(com.cucumber.learning.GoogleTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
```

cucumber.runtime.CucumberException:

```
Classes annotated with @RunWith(Cucumber.class) must not define any
Step Definition or Hook methods. Their sole purpose is to serve as
     an entry point for JUnit. Step Definitions and Hooks should be defined
in their own classes. This allows them to be reused across features.
Offending class: class com.cucumber.learning.GoogleTest

at cucumber.runtime.junit.Assertions.assertNoCucumberAnnotatedMethods(Assertions.java:13)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:40)
at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:80)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:75)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.createRequestAndRun(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:97)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.executeEager(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:78)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:54)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:144)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)


Results :

Tests in error: 
GoogleTest.initializationError » Cucumber 

Classes annotated with @RunWith(Cu...
YoutubeTest.initializationError » Cucumber 

Classes annotated with @RunWith(C...

 Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0

 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 2.375 s
 [INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-23T16:21:53+05:30
 [INFO] Final Memory: 10M/218M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project CucumberModule:   There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to   /home/test/workspace/customparalleltesting/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute cucumber feature file parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034116/how-to-execute-cucumber-feature-file-parallel)

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/41100104/2895913

Answer (score 1):

There are many things which are not correct in your setup, you have to instantiate the browser from cucumber runner class so that all your step definitions can run in that instance any how if you want to run it separately, you have to do something like this :

```
package com.cucumber.learning;

 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
 import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

  public class GoogleTest extends GoogleRunnerIT {


 @Given("go to google")
 public static void main() {

 public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=iHJrV_DiJ8SL8QfEipjgBg");

}

}
```

But efficient way is create a common method in runner class for instantiating and passing the url of your app.!

Comment: Did what you have mentioned, both in GoogleTest.java as well as YoutubeTest.java [extends YoutubeRunnerIT] and instantiated the driver inside the methods. Still cannot execute. I'm adding the console error received in the question for you to review.

Comment: In your cucumber runner class, the Glue is commented any reason for that??

Comment: can you un-comment and try to execute?

Comment: What should I give in glue option? Because my package struct is different.

Comment: in glue you have to give the step definitions path

Comment: Tried just by removing the comment, but didn't work.

Comment: Tried that too.. added this ",glue={"com.cucumber.learning"}".. but didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115402/discussion-between-test-admin-and-igniteram1).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put **forkCount** in the configuration tag of the maven-surefire plugin
With forkCount=4 as in below example it will run 4 Test Classes in parallel which ends with RunnerIT

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>acceptance-test</id>
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*RunnerIT.class</include>
                    </includes>
                    <forkCount>4</forkCount>
                    <parallel>all</parallel>
                    <threadCountSuites>2</threadCountSuites>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Reference From :-
https://opencredo.com/running-cucumber-jvm-tests-in-parallel/

Comment: I added forkCount=2, since I'm having 2 RunnerIT.class, but not working [the tests are executed, but the execution is not parallel. Tests are getting executed one after the another].

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the signature and annotation for the method to be executed in step definition class 
`@Given("^go to google$")
public void goToGoogle() {
     driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/gfe_rd=cr&ei=iHJrV_DiJ8SL8QfEipjgBg");
}`

I am having doubt with the step definition being defined in main method.